# Can I test that a Notification is **NOT** posted?

Tags: ios, swift, tdd, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using TDD with this project and have written a test that uses an `Expectation` to assert that a `Notification` is posted.

However, I realise now that I don't know for certain that the `Notification` is **NOT** being posted in other cases.

Is there a way that I can test that a `Notification` is **NOT** posted in a unit test?

Comment: Hmm... actually, I could inject a NotificationCenter subclass and override the post here. I may do that.